# Django: Inline Form Fields in ModelForm

Tags: django

How to place fields in one line same like I do for ModelAdmin.

In ModelAdmin class we initialize `fields` variable with model class properties like:

```
@admin.register(Profile)
class AdminProfile(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['team', ('first_name', 'last_name'), 'designation', ...]
```

But same if I do for ModelForm's Meta class `fields` variable, then this raises exception, e.g:

```
class PostsModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['team', ('first_name', 'last_name'), 'designation', ...]
```

**RAISED ERROR:**

`TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    sequence item 0: expected string or Unicode, tuple found`

Answer (score 0):

ModelForms don't provide any fancy way to render forms. There are only the [3 defaults methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options), and they aren't flexible. In other words, ModelForms are mostly for constructing form objects from model instances, adding some validation rules etc.

And what you need is [django-cripsy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layouts.html).

Or you can [render your form fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself.

Here is the solution...

Create `ModelForm` sub class

```
class ProfileModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    x_field = forms.CharField(required=True)
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = []
        # Initialize `fields` variable with empty list

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # @TODO: Extra cooking on model instance (self.instance)
        # and self properties like `x_field`
        return super(PostsModelForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Register Model class for Admin and create `ModelAdmin` sub class:

```
@admin.register(Profile)
class AdminProfile(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Assign `ProfileModelForm` to form variable
    form = ProfileModelForm
    ...
    # Here initialize the `fields` variable for `Profile` model fields
    # and `ProfileModelForm` property
    fields = ['team', ('first_name', 'last_name'), 'designation', 'x_field', ...]
```